# TypeError: register_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
import os 
import tkinter.messagebox as tm

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
    """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
    new_frame = frame_class(self)
    if self._frame is not None:
        self._frame.destroy()
    self._frame = new_frame
    self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Please select an option below").pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        tk.Button(self, text="Register",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(register_screen)).pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Login",
                  command=lambda: master.switch_frame(login_screen)).pack()

class register_screen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        global username
        global password
        global username_entry
        global password_entry

        self.username = StringVar()
        self.password = StringVar()

        Label(self, text="Please enter details below").pack()
        Label(self, text="").pack()
        username_lable = Label(self, text="Username * ")
        username_lable.pack()
        username_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.username)
        username_entry.pack()
        password_lable = Label(self, text="Password * ")
        password_lable.pack()
        password_entry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.password, show='*')
        password_entry.pack()
        Label(self, text="").pack()
        Button(self, text="Register", width=10, height=1, command = register_user).pack()

class login_screen(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="Login Page").grid(row=0)

        global username_verify
        global password_verify

        self.username_verify = StringVar()
        self.password_verify = StringVar()

        global username_entry1
        global password_entry1

        tk.Label(self, text = "Username").grid(row = 3, sticky=E)
        username_entry1 = Entry(self,textvariable = username_verify) 
        username_entry1.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

        tk.Label(self, text = "Password").grid(row = 6, sticky=E)
        password_entry1 = Entry(self,show="*",textvariable = password_verify)
        password_entry1.grid(row = 6, column = 1)

        tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Keep Me Logged In").grid(columnspan = 2) 
        tk.Button(self,text= "Login", command= login_verify).grid(row = 8)
```

Got Error: register_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' (or) login_verify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

I am not understanding what I am missing here. I am new to python so, please explain me using references for my further understanding.Please help me out.if there are any mistakes in the rest of the code or any scope for improvement, please provide the suggestions.

```
def register_user(self):

    username_info = self.username.get()
    password_info = self.password.get()

    file = open(r"C:\Users\ashita.gadagotti\Desktop\username_info.txt", "w+")
    file.write(username_info + "\n")
    file.write(password_info)
    file.close()

    username_entry.delete(0, END)
    password_entry.delete(0, END)

    Label(self, text="Registration Success.Please log in with the new credentials.", fg="green", font=("calibri", 11),command = lambda: master.switch_frame(login_page)).pack()

def login_verify(self):
    username1 = self.username_entry1.get()
    password1 = self.password_entry1.get()

    username_entry1.delete(0, END)
    password_entry1.delete(0, END)

    logindetails = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\ashita.gadagotti\Desktop\username_info.txt")
    if username1 == logindetails:
            file1 = open(username1, "r")
            verify = file1.read().splitlines()
            if password1 in verify:
                master.switch_frame(SearchPage)
            else:
                tm.showerror("Login error","password has not been recognized")
    else:
        tm.showerror("Login error","User not found!")

class searchpage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        tk.Label(self, text="SearchPage").grid(row = 0)
        tk.Entry().grid(row = 1)
        tk.Button(self, text="Search")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.title("Equiniti Search Engine")
    app.geometry('1280x720')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

`self` is a reserved keyword in python, meaning that it has a special meaning in the language. See the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) to learn what it means.In general, it is used as a first argument to methods of class in order to access the reference to the object in question.

From your code, I can see two issues

1. Indent `switch_frame` method and its body so that it is recognized as a method of the class
2. `register_user` and `login_verify` seems to be using references to attributes of a class so you need to put them under `login_screen` class definition

Comment: Thank you for the response @gokul_uf. I added the login_verify under login_screen class and register_user under register_screen. It is still showing the same error.